# Functions are not being invoked in ionic for second time

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In my ionic app, I have 2 tabs called `applied` and `rejected`. When I first navigate to the `appliedPage` the method in a constructor is called and it is showing the output, same to the `RejecedPage`. But when I go the third page and click on apply/reject button then the changes should reflect on either `AppliedPage` or `RejectedPage`. But hereafter clicking on the apply or reject, when I navigate to the `applied` or `rejected` page the `Http` in the constructor is not being called. Whenever I open a particular page that page should automatically call a method (from where I retrieve the data from `DB` using `http`). How can I do it?

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
              private getAppliedlist: ActionsProvider)
  {

   console.log('fetching data`);
    this.getAppliedlist.getAppliedList().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.applied = data;
      console.log(this.applied);
    })
  }
```

This above code is from the `AppliedPage`.

Comment: I have updated the question. When I open the applied page It does not fetch the data and also does not display console o/p : as `fetching data`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it within the constructor, you should make use of the `ionic` [lifecycle functions](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/). In this case, the `ionViewWillEnter` function will be perfect

According to the docs, it is called:

> when entering a page, before it becomes the active one. Use it for tasks you want to do every time you enter in the view (setting event listeners, updating a table, etc.).

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  console.log('fetching data`);
  this.getAppliedlist.getAppliedList().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.applied = data;
    console.log(this.applied);
  })
}
```